# Need to check video resolution before transcoding video file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am converting video files using an elastic transcoder. AWS Lambda function get video file from s3 bucket and convert it according to PresetId.

But, I need to compare video file resolution with PresetId. If the video file resolution is higher than the PresetId video resolution, then convert this video file, otherwise do not need to convert all video files.

Comment: whats the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to ffmpeg/ffprobe/ffplay from AWS - is it possible to call them and take their console output? I'm not sure about what's allowed in AWS, but on Desktop you could call ffprobe etc. - it could return text or even JSON.
Many ways are suggested here: [Getting video dimension / resolution / width x height from ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362130/getting-video-dimension-resolution-width-x-height-from-ffmpeg)

One of the suggested ways:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x input.m4v
1280x720
```

Comment: FYI: This post suggests that `ffprobe` is smart enough not to download the whole file: [Get Video Resolution of a Video File using Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539962/174777)